# Design for a JApplet animation using Swing and Threads

Tags: java, swing, animation, applet

I'm trying to implement a small Applet that does some animation. I would like to do the animation in a JPanel and below the Animation JPanel, have play/pause, and skip buttons to control the animation. To do this correctly, I think I need to have the animation in a Thread. (correct?)

My Questions are: Whats is a good way to organize my Classes for this application? How to I get my animation thread to run inside a JPanel?

I've been looking in the tutorials at oracle.com and this is what I have so far...

```
Class AnimationApplet extends JApplet {

...

    public void init(){
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    createGUI();
                }
            });
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TabApplet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TabApplet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

     private void createGUI() {
        AnimationPanel ac = new AnimationPanel();
        this.setConentPane(ac);
     }

} // Class AnimationApplet

class AnimationPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    ...
}
```

Edit: I don't know if this will help, but here's exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm creating a guitar tab player so it would need to continue sliding the notes across the screen and then at certain points (16th notes), check if there are notes to animate. This seems kind of difficult because you can't divide ms by the beats per minute evenly. So for now, I'm thinking of dividing it into 4 or 5 speeds (slowest, slow, medium, etc);

Thanks,

Nate

Comment: Swing and Animation tags added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to use Threads directly since you could simply use a Swing Timer to drive the animation (though understanding that this uses threading behind the scenes).  I would have my animation component extend JPanel as you're doing and draw in its paintComponent method.  I would avoid having any gui or "view" class extend a listener class as you're doing above as that's making a single class do too much.  I'd either use anonymous inner listeners, or private inner class listeners or if complex separate stand-alone listener classes.

Another caveat -- make sure that your paintComponent method does painting and painting only, that it contains no program logic and avoid creating classes or reading in images from within this method.  It needs to be lean and fast.

Comment: Somebody pointed out to me recently that if you are overriding paint()/paintComponent() then JPanel provides no more (useful) functionality than JComponent.

Comment: Thanks for the information Andrew, but can you elaborate on that? What functionality is specifically lost when paintComponent is overridden, and super.paintComponent is called from within?  The JPanel defaults are still true, it still paints its background and is opaque as a JPanel normally is (and where's Rob Camick when you need him?).

Comment: I'll add a Swing and Animation tag, and maybe that'll get Rob's attention. ;)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: Unlike `JComponent`, `JPanel` is double buffered, opaque and has a default layout. Sorry to but in. :-) +1, BTW.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into the Swing Timer.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, your comments are generally the reasons I extend JPanel for simple painting, that is to take advantage of the background painting being built in. Other than that there is not much difference as Andrew says. @trashgod, double buffering should not be an issue since according to (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) the root pane is double buffered so all child components are double buffered even is double buffering isn't explicitly set on the component.

Answer (score 1):

I like `javax.swing.Timer` for animation; here's a simple [applet example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway).